# AsyncTask.cancel only works once

Tags: android, android-asynctask

For some reason my call to `AsyncTask.cancel` only works once, i.e. for the first instance of the task, and never again. The first task cancels beautifully and hits the `onCancelled` method. All the others seem to ignore the `cancel()` call and end up in `onPostExecute`.

The task is executed from a service:

```
public class ZitFtpService extends Service implements ZitFtpServiceInterface
{
//Blah blah

public void connect(String server, int port)
{
    if(!isConnecting){
        isConnecting = true;
        ConnectTask task = new ConnectTask();
        task.execute(server, String.valueOf(port));
    }
    }
    //Blah blah blah
```

As you can see it is a new instance every time.  I can't see why the first one would behave differently from the subsequent ones. The `AsyncTask` is a private inner class:

```
private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        boolean result = false;

        try {
            publishProgress(
                    "start", "Connecting to "+ params[0] + ":" + params[1]);
            Log.v("ZIT", params[0] + " " + params[1] + " " + params.length);
            conn.connect(params[0], Integer.valueOf(params[1]), 1000);
            result = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.e("ZIT", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
                failMessage = e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        return Boolean.valueOf(result);
    }

    private void cancelConnect()  {
        try {
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conn = new ZMobileFTPImpl();
        }

        if(!(dialog==null)) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.v("ZIT", "I was cancelled.");
        isConnecting = false;
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        if(dialog == null) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(progressActivity);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    ConnectTask.this.cancel(true);
                    cancelConnect();
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
            dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        }

        dialog.setMessage(values[1]);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        dialog.dismiss();
        if(!result) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(progressActivity);
            builder.setMessage(failMessage).setTitle("Error");
            failMessage = "";
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });
            AlertDialog failDialog = builder.create();
            failDialog.show();
        }

        isConnecting = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say, but most of all it is some error in your code. You are using global variables within your AsyncTask, also you use that variables to determine whether to run new task or not. Please debug through your task creation process

Answer (score 1):

**[From Doc's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**

There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class to work properly:

- The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of `JELLY_BEAN`.
- The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
- `execute(Params...)` must be invoked on the UI thread.
- Do not call `onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` manually.
- The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

So, you can call an AsyncTask multiple times by creating new instance every time like

```
new ConnectTask().execute(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional as you can only execute an AsyncTask instance once, you can run `task.execute` multiple times though...

Anyhow, I believe you forgot to add the super.onCancelled in following override:

```
@Override
public void onCancelled() {
    //...
    super.onCancelled();
}
```

Try if that helped, and otherwise you should share the error or log so we can troubleshoot that :)